# What do these Diagnosis Error Codes mean?

Tags: kia

A transmission mechanic gave me the following error codes for my Kia Sedona 2005 model. Not sure what they mean and which ones I need to have fixed.

- P2422
- P0116
- P0304
- P02015

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [troublecodes.net](http://www.troublecodes.net/OBD2/Pcodes.shtml):

P0116: Engine Coolant Temperature Circuit Range/Performance Problem

P0304: Cylinder 4 Misfire Detected

The other two are not listed here.  Check your coolant, clear out the codes and see if any show up again.  If they do, then it's time to get the car into a mechanic.